# display the image from remote database in windows phone 8

Tags: c#-4.0, windows-phone-8

I need to display the images from remote database.here I have a code to display images from local file.But I can't get it from remote server

`C#` code

```
DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();
        List<string> files = new List<string>() { "http://technomindtech.com/1tele-pixel.com/ad/banner.jpg", "http://technomindtech.com/1tele-pixel.com/ad/logo_banner.jpg", "http://technomindtech.com/1tele-pixel.com/ad/images.jpeg" };


        List<BitmapImage> images = new List<BitmapImage>();
            int current = 0;

                foreach (string file in files)
                {
                    BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage(new Uri(file, UriKind.Relative));
                    images.Add(image);
                }

                timer = new DispatcherTimer();
                timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3);
                timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_Tick);

                timer.Start();

     void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                Image1.Source = images[current];

                current++;
                if (current >= files.Count)
                    current = 0;
            }
```

`Xaml` code

```
<Image x:Name="Image1"  Stretch="Fill" Width="410" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Margin="-8,0,-29,0"  />
```

but it throws Uri exception it can't show the image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your foreach block, when creating an image from the Uri, you are stating that the path is relative, but it is actually absolute. So, modifying the statement should work:

```
BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage(new Uri(file, UriKind.Absolute));
```